# upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io

I build and chatroom app with the Socket.io,
but after deploying to the production server, there are lots of error in Nginx's log:

```
2016/08/07 09:15:05 [error] 14069#14069: *7875548 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 171.4.246.202, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=EIuZoogwZQLJRqqVAMDl&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10001/socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=EIuZoogwZQLJRqqVAMDl&transport=websocket", host: "chat.geek4it.com"
2016/08/07 09:15:05 [error] 14069#14069: *7875548 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 171.4.246.202, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=EIuZoogwZQLJRqqVAMDl&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10007/socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=EIuZoogwZQLJRqqVAMDl&transport=websocket", host: "chat.geek4it.com"
2016/08/07 09:15:25 [error] 14070#14070: *7877071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.24.40.131, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10007/socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF", host: "chat.geek4it.com:80"
2016/08/07 09:15:25 [error] 14070#14070: *7877071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.24.40.131, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10003/socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF", host: "chat.geek4it.com:80"
2016/08/07 09:15:25 [error] 14070#14070: *7877071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.24.40.131, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10002/socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF", host: "chat.geek4it.com:80"
2016/08/07 09:15:25 [error] 14070#14070: *7877071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.24.40.131, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10001/socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF", host: "chat.geek4it.com:80"
2016/08/07 09:15:25 [error] 14070#14070: *7877071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.24.40.131, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10006/socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF", host: "chat.geek4it.com:80"
2016/08/07 09:15:25 [error] 14070#14070: *7877071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.24.40.131, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10008/socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF", host: "chat.geek4it.com:80"
2016/08/07 09:15:25 [error] 14070#14070: *7877071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.24.40.131, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10005/socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF", host: "chat.geek4it.com:80"
2016/08/07 09:15:25 [error] 14070#14070: *7877071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.24.40.131, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10004/socket.io/?transport=websocket&sid=Vc0WK_sK5E2OW_BKAJXF", host: "chat.geek4it.com:80"
2016/08/07 09:15:29 [error] 14069#14069: *7877292 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.25.177.189, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=QPdEtaKYseDpI2HkAJrB&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10008/socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=QPdEtaKYseDpI2HkAJrB&transport=websocket", host: "chat.geek4it.com"
2016/08/07 09:15:29 [error] 14069#14069: *7877292 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.25.177.189, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=QPdEtaKYseDpI2HkAJrB&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10002/socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=QPdEtaKYseDpI2HkAJrB&transport=websocket", host: "chat.geek4it.com"
2016/08/07 09:15:29 [error] 14069#14069: *7877292 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.25.177.189, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=QPdEtaKYseDpI2HkAJrB&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10003/socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=QPdEtaKYseDpI2HkAJrB&transport=websocket", host: "chat.geek4it.com"
2016/08/07 09:15:29 [error] 14069#14069: *7877292 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.25.177.189, server: chat.geek4it.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=QPdEtaKYseDpI2HkAJrB&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.30.31.1:10006/socket.io/?EIO=3&sid=QPdEtaKYseDpI2HkAJrB&transport=websocket", host: "chat.geek4it.com"
```

Server: [Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io)

Android: [socket.io-client-java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)

iOS: [Socket.IO-Client-Swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)

Server: AWS EC2

Nginx: nginx/1.11.3

Server 1: Nginx

Server 2: 8 socket.io instance written with Node.js (Running with docker container)

**Server 1:**

Nginx Config:

```
upstream chatroom_nodes {
    ip_hash;
    server 172.30.31.1:10001 weight=10 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
    server 172.30.31.1:10002 weight=10 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
    server 172.30.31.1:10003 weight=10 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
    server 172.30.31.1:10004 weight=10 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
    server 172.30.31.1:10005 weight=10 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
    server 172.30.31.1:10006 weight=10 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
    server 172.30.31.1:10007 weight=10 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
    server 172.30.31.1:10008 weight=10 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test.geek4it.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/geek4it/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/geek4it/error.log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://chatroom_nodes;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_buffers 8 24k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    }
}
```

**Server 2:**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
5e4651be48b5         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:10004->3000/tcp   chatroom-4_1
6fedbde6383e         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:10005->3000/tcp   chatroom-5_1
129e8ae422be         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:10002->3000/tcp   chatroom-2_1
857d03c18649         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:10008->3000/tcp   chatroom-8_1
625dc44e81ef         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:10000->3000/tcp   chatroom-0_1
b99334904496         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:10006->3000/tcp   chatroom-6_1
ea648a3913d6         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:10007->3000/tcp   chatroom-7_1
4a8884303dbc         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:10001->3000/tcp   chatroom-1_1
d83e11a1fca5         registry.geek4it.com:5000/chat-runtime:130   "/bin/bash /opt/chatr"   26 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:10003->3000/tcp   chatroom-3_1
```

PS: I use the http protocol like: http://xxxxx to connect to the server.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the proxy timeouts? In your case, you're hitting a read timeout, so [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) will be most relevant, but there are other timeout options you can configure.